# What is this small unconnected solder blob on this PCB?

Tags: pcb, reverse-engineering, manufacturing

There's a small solder blob in the middle of this one-sided PCB (a switch-mode power supply), surrounded by unmasked board. The blob is 1.5mm in diameter, and the non-masked area is 4mm in diameter. There's nothing on the other side of the board, and there is no hole.

[image: PCB with blob]

What's the purpose of this blob? My guess is some kind of manufacturing artifact, but I'm not sure exactly.

Comment: Possibly a marker put in as a drill guide before drilling and slot cutting begins. Often many boards are on a sheet with a stack of 5 or more sheets. There needs to be an absolute ref marker for drilling to be precise. That's my guess.

Comment: @Sparky256 I don't believe this is the case--it's just a blob of solder on the bottom of the board, it doesn't pass all the way through.

Comment: Then read Dave Tweeds more accurate answer. It is a ref maker for the ABS position of parts, one of several that can be on a board. This board has one as it is for through-hole parts, so great accuracy is not needed.

Comment: @Sparky256 and I did accept that answer :). I appreciate how helpful you and everyone else are here, even though it's clear that I know nothing about the subject.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's most likely a type of [fiducial marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker#Printed_circuit_boards), used by a pick-and-place machine to correctly place the SMD parts on the copper side of the board.

Answer (score 8):

That is definitely a type of fiducial marker by the existence of the solder mask clearance. A solder blob forms on the exposed copper when the board is put through the wave solder (by this stage is has served its purpose of a reference point during etching or placement). Normally there are 2 at least 2 markers to allow for accurate X and Y placement.

Comment: And you can see that it has been wave soldered because: A) There's a lot of hole-mounted components. B) The SMD components are glued. C) Every piece of exposed copper has solder on it.

Comment: You don‘t need more than one per board if your boards are panelized. The machine will use the same fiducial on several boards to check the entire panel‘s alignment.

Comment: @Crazor Ah, that explains why there is only one on this board! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Its a fiducial.
Seems like the designer forgot to remove solder paste marking of the fiducial in the Gerber files.

Comment: That board was wave soldered.   Solder mask is kind of irrelevant here. ;-)